# How to align divs like an incomplete table?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I'm building an e-commerce site using vue.js, and my product listings align in a strange way, like shown in the image below.

[image: Misaligned divs]

I am trying to achieve this effect shown below.

[image]

Here is a snippet of the code

```
<template>
   <div class="products">
      <div class="prod-container">
         <div class="bangles" v-for="product in products" v-bind:key="product.id" style="width: 16rem;">
            <ProductSlide class="slide" type="bangle" v-bind:product="product"/>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
   import ProductSlide from '@/components/productSlide.vue'
   export default {
      name: 'Bangles',
      components: {
         ProductSlide
      }
   }
<script>

<style type="text/css" scoped>
   .prod-container {
      margin-right: 5%;
   }
   .bangles {
      display: inline-flex;
      margin: 1%;
   }

   @media screen and (max-width:639px) {
      .bangles {
         margin-left: 25%;
      }
   }

   .products {
      margin-bottom: 5em;
   }
</style>
```

I've tried messing around with the position, display, width and width units - none if it seems to work at the moment.

Comment: It is not possible get results as in the pictures with above HTML and CSS code. Please check again all styles. By the way, your CSS code is outside `style` tag and attribute `class` in first `div` is not properly closed with quotation mark. Could you provide us with working code snippet preview?

Comment: Changes have been made, my code is exactly as shown, miscopied it! Thank you for pointing that out. This is my code exactly as is, and unfortunately this is the result i am getting. What do you think could be the problem here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
When I removed the width from the ProductSlide Tag, everything seemed to fall in place. If someone knows why or how this happened, let me know!

This is what my code looks like now:

```
<template>
<div class="products">
<div class="prod-container">
  <div class="bangles" v-for="product in products" v-bind:key="product.id">
    <ProductSlide class="slide" type="bangle" v-bind:product="product"/>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
import ProductSlide from '@/components/productSlide.vue'
export default {
  name: 'Bangles',
  components: {
    ProductSlide
  }
}
<script>

<style type="text/css" scoped>
.slide {
    position: relative;
}

.prod-container {
    margin-left: 15%;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.bangles {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-top: 2%;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    }
@media screen and (max-width:639px) {
    .bangles {
        margin-left: 25%;
    }
}

.products {
   margin-bottom: 5em;
}

</style>
```

Comment: i'm edit your code and found extra closing `</div>` after `div` with class name `prod-container`.

Comment: Have made the changes, I have some other non-related items I can't throw on the snippet so its copy paste error. Thank you for the pointing it out though !

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky without a prototype, but if I'm understanding your scenario correctly I would use CSS Grid: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Your styles will look something like this

```
...
.bangles {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1%;
  # set your grid to 3 columns of equal width
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); 
}
```

You can reduce the number of columns in your @media queries as desired.

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying, but unfortunately it didn't work. I think it might be an issue with one of my other components, you can never tell with these things sometimes